# Make vim plugin Syntastic mark more than the first error in php

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugins

I'm using vim on mac (both command line & MacVim) and installed the [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) plugin for syntax error checking. I'm now using it and its standard php syntax_checker for php coding, but if there's more than one error in the php file, only the first error gets marked with the `>>`. Also the balloon only appears for the first error.
Is there an option one can set to show all errors & warnings in a file?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid that it's the default behavior of `$ php -l filename`. You may want to [take a look around for another linter…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378959/is-there-a-static-code-analyzer-like-lint-for-php-files)

Answer (score 0):

Syntastic supports [three different checkers](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/tree/master/syntax_checkers/php) for php;

1. php itself using the `-l` option
2. [PHP Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org/)
3. [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer)

Try installing 2 or 3.